# Driver: Reception overrun: Messages are lost

Tags: canoe

[image: Measurement setup]

---

[image: simulation setup]

---

The above two pictures are my measurement and simulation setups respectively. The Replay block plays a blf file of length 6 minutes containing total of 2,413,161 CAN frames from two CAN channels.

---

[image: Test setup]

---

The above picture explains the bench setup. Canoe reads the blf file and transmits the CAN frames on two CAN channels. Microcontroller (MuC) receives the CAN frames converts them in to Ethernet IPV4 UDP packet and transmit again to the Canoe.

When i run this configuration, i am getting below errors. 
1. System - CAN driver: Reception overrun - messages are lost 
2. System   CAN X : Message with ID = XXX could not be sent. Driver error 11 in TransmitCANFrame, "XL_ERR_QUEUE_IS_FULL" 
3. System   Warning: replay loading delay(s)
System  ReplayBlock 1(blf_file.blf): 15 times, 7347.46 ms total

I assumes this was due to Canoe performance issue or CAN driver issue. So I did the below steps. 
1. Modified the CANCaseXL Receive latency->Very fast under Vector hardware Config. 
2. Increased the Transmit queue settings->32768 (maximum) under Vector hardware config -> Global settings. 
3. I disabled all except one logging block (blf) [As you can see in the measurement setup].

But i still experience the same errors. What could be the problem? Is there any other ways to resolve this?

Comment: Check the bitrate of your can busses in the hardware config. Is it really set to 500 kbps?
The error messages indicate that the CAN messages cannot be transmitted as fast as the replay block wants.
Is your MCU correctly receiving the messages? Maybe an ACK is missing an CANoe tries to retransmit the messages?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have termination on both CANs (120 Ohm).

Such error indicates lack of termination.